# JobSchedule and static anonymous AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-jobscheduler

I am learning how to use `JobSchedule` in Android in combination with `AsyncTasks`. Following some guides I have the following `JobService`implementation:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class TaskJobService extends JobService {

    private WaitTask mWaitTask = null;

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(final JobParameters params) {
        mWaitTask = new WaitTask(){
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                jobFinished(params, !result);
            }
        };
        mWaitTask.execute();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        if (mWaitTask != null){
            mWaitTask.cancel(true);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

and in my `MainActivity:`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int JOB_ID = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//        WaitTask waitTask = new WaitTask();
//        waitTask.execute();
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, TaskJobService.class);
        JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        jobScheduler.schedule(new JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID,componentName).setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY).build());
    }

    public void startMain2(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I get the warning in my `JobService-class` that leaks might occur:

```
This AsyncTask class should be static or leaks might occur 
A static field will leak contexts.  Non-static inner classes have an implicit reference to their outer class. If that outer class is for example a Fragment or Activity, then this reference means that the long-running handler/loader/task will hold a reference to the activity which prevents it from getting garbage collected.  Similarly, direct field references to activities and fragments from these longer running instances can cause leaks.  ViewModel classes should never point to Views or non-application Contexts.
```

The thing is that I want to `Task` to continue even though I go to `MainActivity2`.

Is it enough to call `jobFinished` as I do? Or is more needed to avoid memory leaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a non-static inner class, it holds a reference to containing class. In your case `WaitTask` is inner anonymous class which might live longer than your `TaskJobService` since `WaitTask` has implicit reference to your service class. This will prevent your `TaskJobService` from being garbage collected which would lead to memory leak.

The solution would be to either create a static nested class or use top-level class directly.

Comment: Ok, but will the AsyncTask continue to execute even if we change activity then? I got the impression that so is not the case when I read the doc. But I might have misunderstood it.

Comment: The AsyncTask will continue to execute until and unless you cancel it. If you start a AsyncTask in one activity and navigate to another one, the task will still run through its completion. It could cause memory leak because, its still holding context of previous activity.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I wanted to make sure how it works before I put it into bigger projects.

Comment: Try to avoid usage of AsyncTask as much as possible. If you do use, test for memory leaks. For long running tasks consider using Service/IntentService/ForegroundService. Use AsyncTask for trivial use-cases.